# Pro Tools 11: Pros and Cons

Tags: pro-tools-11

Has anyone had any experience with Pro Tools 11? How is it?

Answer (score 1):

Just posted all my thoughts on [my blog](http://www.protoolsprofessional.com) over the weekend fyi.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Pro Tools 11 on my laptop and it is working well for me. I am currently editing dialogue, and there are no glitches, or hanging on a MacBook Pro running 10.8.4.  Visually the software has improved, and the new meters are fun, I have a de-esser running and you can see the gain reduction levels down the side of the track meter.

However, I won't be able to upgrade the software at work as we will have to upgrade all of the Avid hardware as well, which is a shame, but I completely understand why.